# Looking to Increase Speed of Snake Every Time it grows in Snake Game

Tags: java, list, user-interface, timer

I am making a snake game using linked lists and such for practice, and I want to increase the speed of the snake using Timers in Java every time the snake grows in length. So far I have the basic game set up, with multiple food pellets and pellets that can kill the snake. But I am stuck trying to get the snake to go faster every time it grows.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SnakeGame extends JFrame {
    // A snake is just a list of coordinates (java.util.LinkedList, not our LinkedList)
    private LinkedList<Coordinate> snake = new LinkedList<Coordinate>();
    // The snake grows when it eats food
    //private Coordinate food = new Coordinate();

    private List<Coordinate> objects = new ArrayList<>();

    // The game is on or over
    private static enum Game { ON, OVER};
    private Game status = Game.ON;

    // Repeatedly moves the snake
    private Timer timer;

    // The snake can move in one of 4 directions
    public static enum Direction { UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT };
    // The snake's current direction (heading). Default: moving right
    private Direction heading = Direction.RIGHT;

    /**
     *  An (x,y) coordinate in a 64 by 48 grid
     */
    public static class Coordinate {
        public final int x;
        public final int y;
        public boolean food = false;
        // By default, construct a random coordinate not too far from the wall
        Coordinate() {
            this.x = new Random().nextInt(60) + 2;
            this.y = new Random().nextInt(40) + 2;
        }
        Coordinate(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    // The snake can't switch to the opposite direction
    public boolean oppositeDirection(Direction newHeading) {
        return (heading == Direction.UP && newHeading == Direction.DOWN) ||
                (heading == Direction.DOWN && newHeading == Direction.UP) ||
                (heading == Direction.LEFT && newHeading == Direction.RIGHT) ||
                (heading == Direction.RIGHT && newHeading == Direction.LEFT);
    }

    // Update the heading based on the new heading
    public void changeHeading(Direction newHeading) {
        if (!oppositeDirection(newHeading)) {
            heading = newHeading;
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Handle keyboard input (arrows change the snake's heading)
     */
    private class KeyControl implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            Direction newHeading = heading;

            switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: case KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT:
                    newHeading = Direction.LEFT; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: case KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT:
                    newHeading = Direction.RIGHT; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP: case KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP:
                    newHeading = Direction.UP; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: case KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN:
                    newHeading = Direction.DOWN; break;
            }
            changeHeading(newHeading);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    }


    @Override
    // This view renders the snake and food
    // Each snake coordinate is a 10x10 pixel square
    // This method is called from repaint() from AWT
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 640, 480);
        Color green = new Color(0,128,0);
        g.setColor(green);

        for (Coordinate c : snake) {
            g.fillRect(c.x*10, c.y*10, 10, 10);
        }
        
        for (Coordinate object : objects) {
            if(object.food){
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            }else{
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
            g.fillOval(object.x*10, object.y*10, 10, 10);
        }

    }

    // When the snake moves, it can hit the wall, hit the food, poison (not implemented) or itself (not implemented)
    public void move() {
        Coordinate newHead = newHead();

        if (hitTheWall(newHead)) {
            status = Game.OVER;
            return; // will return back to where this method is called
        }

        snake.addFirst(newHead);    // java.util.LinkedList.addFirst()

        if (hitTheFood(newHead)) {
            // new object should always be added when the snake eats one
            Coordinate object = new Coordinate();
            object.food = true;
            objects.add(object);
        } else {
            snake.removeLast();
        }
    }
    // The snake's heading determines its new head coordinate
    private Coordinate newHead() {
        Coordinate head, newHead;
        head = snake.getFirst();    // java.util.LinkedList.getFirst()

        switch (heading) {
            case DOWN: newHead = new Coordinate(head.x, head.y + 1); break;
            case LEFT: newHead = new Coordinate(head.x - 1, head.y); break;
            case RIGHT: newHead = new Coordinate(head.x + 1, head.y); break;
            case UP: newHead = new Coordinate(head.x, head.y - 1); break;
            // The default case is never reached because we have only 4 events.
            default: newHead = new Coordinate(); break;
        }
        return newHead;
    }
    private boolean hitTheFood(Coordinate newHead) {
        for (Coordinate obj : objects) {
            boolean hit = newHead.x == obj.x && newHead.y == obj.y && obj.food;
            if(hit){
                objects.remove(obj);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean hitTheWall(Coordinate head) {

        for (Coordinate obj : objects){
            if(head.x == obj.x && head.y == obj.y && !obj.food)
                return true;
        }
        for (Coordinate obj : snake){
            if(head.x == obj.x && head.y == obj.y && !obj.food)
                return true;
        }

        if (head.x == 64 || head.y == 48 || head.x == 0 || head.y == 0)
            return true;


        return  false;
    }

    /**
     * The timer moves the snake using this class.
     */
    private class SnakeMover implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        // Listening Action (in this case Timer - every certain millisecond) and execute this method
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            move();
            repaint();  // from AWT library. It will call paint() automatically
            if (status == Game.OVER) {
                playAgain("The snake's dead");
            }
        }
    }

    // Ask the player what to do when the game is over
    private void playAgain(String message) {
        String[] options = new String[] {"Play again","Quit"};
        int choice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, message, "Game over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,options,options[0]);

        if (choice == 0) {
            initialize();
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    // Initialize game (snake, food, etc)
    private void initialize() {
        status = Game.ON;

        // Make a small snake with 1 node (a 10x10 pixel coordinate)
        snake.clear(); // remove all of the elements of the LinkedList
        snake.add(new Coordinate()); // append the new element to the end of the LinkedList
        
        // creating some foods 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
            Coordinate object = new Coordinate();
            object.food= true;
            objects.add(object);
        }

        // creating some poisons 
        for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
            Coordinate object = new Coordinate();
            objects.add(object);
        }
        
        

    }
    public SnakeGame() {

        setSize(640, 480);  // Window size - pixel
        setTitle("Snake Game");
        setVisible(true);



        // Update the snake's direction using keyboard arrows
        // Event Handler: addKeyListener is from AWT library. This is how to "register" event
        addKeyListener(new KeyControl());

        // Make the snake move every 150 milliseconds
        timer = new Timer(150, new SnakeMover());
        timer.start();
        

        // Initialize game (snake, food)
        initialize();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SnakeGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: [DIfference between Java and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)